# How do I add a real-time battery status icon to a Zepp Watchface?

Tags: watchface, zeppos

I have 10 images of a battery status icon (at percentages of 10%, 20%, 30%, etc.). What am I supposed to name these images to make a battery indicator graphic on a Zepp watch face?

In the "battery" component, there is a "image progress". I'm assuming this is what I need, but I don't know what to name the images for the slice.

Also, what is the difference between "single display" and "continuous display"?